# Flask on mod_wsgi, MarkupSafe UnicodeDecode error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have a Flask application running under mod_wsgi on apache2 server.

There is a simple view function inside the application, which gives some cyrillic characters to `render_template()` :

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return render_template('test.html', string='Немного кириллических символов')
```

test.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
{% if string %}
<h1>{{string}}</h1>
{% else %}
nope
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

When the app is working with built-in Flask server everything is perfectly fine.

However, when I run it on apache server, `/test` returns a 500 error.

Traceback shows that `_native.escape()` function from MarkupSafe is trying to decode the given string with 'ascii' codec, which is surprising for me.

Extract from the traceback:

```
  File "/var/www/jusite/jusite/templates/test.html", line 7, in top-level template code
    <h1>{{string}}</h1>
  File "/var/www/jusite/jusite/juvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/markupsafe/_native.py", line 22, in escape
    return Markup(text_type(s)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Full traceback is avaliable [here](http://pastebin.com/U9zf2CfE)

Comment: Is the user set in `WSGIDaemonProcess` the same as the user that runs the app?

Comment: I suppose the group is the same as well, right?

Comment: @ipinak right, the group is the same

Comment: Then I've run out of reasons

Comment: Your `mod_wsgi` may have been running a different version of Python completely. If it was Python 2, your solution might have been to write `u'Немного ...'`.